# Laravel 5 - (@extends, @sections,...) not working

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am new to Laravel and I on the website I try to make all @xy aren't working and I don't find the problem. My code is following for /home:

```html
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
<h1>Home</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
@endsection

@section('sidebar')
  @parent
  <p>This is appended to the sidebar </p>
@endsection
```

And the code for /layouts/app.blade.php is following:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>FIXME</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div="app">
      @include('inc.navbar')

      <div class="container">
          @if(Request::is('/'))
          @include('inc.showcase')
          @endif
      </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-8">
        @include('inc.messages')
        @yield('content')
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-4">
        @include('inc.sidebar')
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>

    <footer id="footer" class="text-center">
      <p>Copyright 2018 &copy; FIXME </p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

The navbar is a bootstrap template.

Comment: do you get an error?

Comment: which laravel version you are using?

Comment: show your routes, controller, where do you call view?

Comment: `<div="app">` doesn't seem like valid html

Comment: Are you sure you have files saved with double-extension: .blade.php? For example: something.blade.php. Main blade is master.blade.php unless you modified this part of app.

Comment: @Jerodev, how is that? IMO looks valid.

Comment: I don't get an error or something... I use Laravel 5.4 but on the Website it doesn't recognize the @xy, it just returns them as text.

Comment: your home/ file have proper extension home.blade.php?

Comment: And they all have proper extensions, yes.

Comment: In the father layout you didn't specify any section, for example: "
        #section('sidebar') This is the master sidebar #show " so you can do what you did on the child layout "#section('sidebar') #parent "

Comment: I specified the sidebar in views/inc/sidebar.blade.php such as messages, showcase and navbar, if this is what you mean. @MeowMeowI'maCow

Comment: Did you try to put the includes inside a section?

Comment: @MeowMeowI'maCow I just tried that, but sadly it didn't help

Comment: @spectatorx It looks like it's supposed to be `<div id="app">` or `<div class="app">`; an attribute specification must start with a name or name token.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Doctype html>

<html>

<head>

   @include('includes.head')

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

   <header class="row">

       @include('includes.header')

   </header>

   <div id="main" class="row">

           @yield('content')

   </div>

   <footer class="row">

       @include('includes.footer')

   </footer>

</div>

</body>

</html>
```

If you still have issue or required for information you visit my article : 
Create Layout in Laravel Using Blade Templating Engine